# Checkbox filter in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have an array of objects (tasks) in a table and two checkboxes: "Night", "Day".

I want the next scenario: if checkbox Night is checked, only tasks with a property "Night" are left in a table. If checkbox Day is checked, only tasks with a property "Day" are left in a table (and "Night" tasks are left  as well if checkbox "Night" is still checked). And the third checkbox "Reset" resets the filter.

Maybe it's better to use another way for sorting, for example pipes?

Here's [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qQiIuTtuqcnnCkZBDQI6?p=preview).
Here's a code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="getNight()">Night
    <input type="checkbox" (click)="getDay()">Day
    <input type="checkbox">Uncheck
    <br><br>
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <td>{{task.chkBoxImageUrl}}</td>
        <td>{{task.id}}</td>
        <td>{{task.val}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  tasks: Array<{chkBoxImageUrl: string, id: string, val: string, 
checked:boolean}> = [
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http1", id: "item1", val: "Night", checked: false},
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http2", id: "item2", val: "Day", checked: false},
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http3", id: "item3", val: "Night", checked: false},
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http4", id: "item4", val: "Day", checked: false},
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http4", id: "item4", val: "Morning", checked: false},
    {chkBoxImageUrl: "http4", id: "item4", val: "Evening", checked: false}
  ];

  getNight() {
   console.log(this.tasks[2].val); // Night 
   // return this.tasks.filter(obj => obj.checked).map(obj => obj.val);
   if(this.tasks.val == 'Night') {
    return this.tasks.filter(obj => obj.checked).map(obj => obj.val == 'Night');
   } else {
     console.log('666666');
   }
  };
  getDay() {
   return this.tasks.filter(obj => obj.checked).map(obj => obj.val);
  };
  getCheckedCount(){
    return this.getCheckedValues().length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular documentation discourages the use of pipes for filtering and ordering. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Answer (score 1):

Updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VG2KLVMP8GvUHouJemJL?p=preview) here

In order to filter the `tasks` array the `Night` and `Day` checkbox values need to be accessible. One way of doing this is by creating instance variables `night` and `day` and using the `ngModel` directive to bind them to the respective checkboxes.

Component:

```
night: boolean = false;
day: boolean = false;
```

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="night">Night
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="day">Day
```

`night` and `day` will now be true when checked and false when unchecked. These values can be used to filter the `tasks` array.

Component:

```
interface Task {
  chkBoxImageUrl: string;
  id: string;
  val: string;
  checked:boolean;
}

getTasks(): Array<Task> {
  return this.tasks.filter(obj => this.night && obj.val === 'Night' || this.day && obj.val === 'Day');
}
```

View:

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of getTasks()">
```

The getTasks() method returns an array of tasks, filtered conditionally on the values of `night` and `day`. This is then bound to the view.

To clear the checkboxes when the Uncheck checkbox is checked, the values of `night` and `day` can be reset to false.

Component:

```
uncheck() {
  this.night = false;
  this.day = false;
}
```

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="uncheck()">Uncheck
```

On click, the other checkboxes are reset which changes the result of `getTasks()`

Comment: One of the variants I had tried before was something like this and I didn't use that variant because the tasks must be visible on page load and the checkboxes must be unchecked. Filtering must work after checking the checkboxes. 
In other words expected result: page opens and we see all the tasks and after checking checkboxes filter begins it's job.

Comment: I mean when the page opens the table shouldn't be empty, all the tasks (there are 6 tasks) must be in the table and all checkboxes should be unchecked. When we check checkbox "Night", only night tasks should be left in a table. The same is for the checkbox "Day".

Comment: You can extend this by adding an if condition within or before the return statement to only filter if `night` and `day` are not both false

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could use some refactoring because it isn't pretty ... but I updated your plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/PaHGSZW69Wl8tC1o2wEo?p=preview. You may want to do a little more work to it to clean up my code.

I changed the html to be this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click) = "filterTasks('Night')">Night
<input type="checkbox" (click) = "filterTasks('Day')">Day
```

So it calls a single method instead of two different ones.

The filterTask method then looks like this:

```
  filterTasks(value: string) {
    if (value === 'Night') { this.nightChecked = !this.nightChecked }
    if (value === 'Day') { this.dayChecked = !this.dayChecked }
   this.filteredTasks = this.tasks.filter(obj => 
                 (this.nightChecked && obj.val === "Night") || 
                 (this.dayChecked && obj.val === "Day"));
  }
```

This might work better using data binding ([(ngModel)] to set the two properties instead of using the (click) event. (And I see that is what the other answer did.)